# Init, process and return in racket

Tags: racket

While coding on Racket I often meet a situation when I get some value, then I need to process it somehow and then return it:

```
(let ([result (compute-some-value)])
  (process-somehow result)
  result)
```

where `process-somehow` returns '`void`'.

This boilerplate piece of code looks just wrong. Does racket have some construction to describe this pattern more compactly (in one or two lines), like `begin0` or `aif` or I need to write my own anaphoric macro for that?

To clarify a question, I'm looking for built-in racket construction to be able to write something like

```
(init-and-process (compute-some-value) 
                  process-somehow)
```

or

```
(init-and-process (compute-some-value) 
                  (process-somehow it))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a built-in procedure for this, but it's easy to define your own reusable procedure:

```
(define (init-and-process compute process)
  (let ([result (compute)])
    (process result)
    result))
```

Use it like this:

```
(init-and-process compute-some-value process-somehow)
; => returns (compute-some-value)
```

Comment: Thank you, I just wanted to acknowledge that there is not such built-in procedure!